# Why is ">" (greater than symbol) supported in XML attributes while "<" (less than symbol) is not?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-validation

When I was trying to validate my XML files, I found that ">" (greater than symbol) is supported in XML attributes, while "<" (less than symbol) is not.

For example, the following XML element is valid:

```xml
<formula expression="a > 0" />
```

However, the following XML element is invalid:

```xml
<formula expression="a < 0" />
```

The error message says: `error on line 1 at column 24: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values`.

I thought that both "<" and ">" needs to be escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but it seems that only "<" needs to be escaped. Why is that? Is there a specification for this behavior? Thanks.

Note: I'm using an online XML validator at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp.